# Bootstrap datepicker split issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using a bootstrap datepicker.
While sending the values from datepicker to server my format is mm/dd/yyyy For example: 06/24/2015

When I get the values back from the server ("06/24/2015"), I am trying to fill the datepicker input with 06/24/2015.

For this I am trying to do something like this:

```
$scope.startDate = ($scope.startDate == null) ? null : new Date($scope.startDate);
```

Now the $scope.startDate is Wed Jun 24 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)

Then I am formatting it to display the date in the datepicker input like this:

```
$scope.startDate = $filter('date')($scope.startDate,'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Now the value is 06/24/2015

Everything works fine but I see a script error saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at createParser (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:8)
    at parse (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:8)
    at m (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:8)
    at link.k.$render (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:23295)
    at l.$digest (angular.js:14235)
    at l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
    at l (angular.js:9659)
    at S (angular.js:9849)
    at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (angular.js:9790)
```

I searched a lot of questions and most of them say that this is a bug in datepicker and is available on github master and not yet released.
I wanted to make sure the way I am parsing the dates is correct? Is there a better way to handle this problem and avoid getting the script error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally server data would take a while after your app is initialized. In the mean time datepicker is trying to process a null in ng-model.

While you can certainly wait for a fix from bootstrap, but I think you can consider initialize a date before server data is available, like today's date, or any appropriate date.

`$scope.startDate = ($scope.startDate == null) ? new Date() : new Date($scope.startDate);`

**Edit:** I've written a simple datepicker in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/loserodofo/1/edit?html,js,output) but can't seem to get your error in console. Maybe you can update it and reproduce?

Comment: How about `$scope.startDate =  new Date()` at the start of controller?

Comment: I realised that you were using ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js and I was using version # 11. When I replaced it with the 13.0 version I couldn't see the script error. Thanks for the jsbin code. It really helped me!